# Can Github display diffs between two tags, *within a folder*?

Tags: github, diff, git-diff

Suppose I have a Github project: https://github.com/tom-lord/my_awesome_app (not a real link )

The "main" application's code is within an `app/` folder, and there are also API clients defined within other folders:

- https://github.com/tom-lord/my_awesome_app/tree/master/clients/python
- https://github.com/tom-lord/my_awesome_app/tree/master/clients/ruby
- https://github.com/tom-lord/my_awesome_app/tree/master/clients/etc

Each API client has its own version number, and its own `Changelog.md`.

When a new version of any client is released, a `git tag` is automatically generated. For example, `ruby-v123.45.6`. This is primarily used for deployments, but also means we can *sort-of* show diffs between versions within Github, for example:

https://github.com/tom-lord/my_awesome_app/compare/ruby-v123.45.5...ruby-v123.45.6

**However**, here's the thing: It's not a perfect comparison, because it will also display any *code changes in other folders*. That adds a lot of "unrelated noise" to the diff.

Is there any way *within the Github UI* (or at least within the browser) to filter for file changes within a folder? Ideally I'd like to be able to do this:

https://github.com/tom-lord/my_awesome_app/compare/ruby-v123.45.5...ruby-v123.45.6?path=/clients/ruby/**/*

...Similar to what can be achieved within [Github's advanced search tool](https://github.com/search/advanced).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, Github's advanced search [only displays results from the main branch](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/about-github-code-search#limitations):

> We currently only support searching for code on the default branch of a repository. The query length is limited to 1000 characters.

So I don't think this is possible, in Github's UI.

However, it can be done on the command line:

```
git diff ruby-v123.45.5 ruby-v123.45.6 -- clients/ruby
```

Other useful commands are to just show a list of files changed:

```
git diff ruby-v123.45.5 ruby-v123.45.6 --stat -- clients/ruby
```

Or a log between them:

```
git log ruby-v123.45.5..ruby-v123.45.6 -- clients/ruby
```

You may need to do `git pull --tags` (or a full `git fetch`) first.